# Existence of a symplectic orthogonal transformation between A and B

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's consider two symmetric real  matrices $A$ and $B$ of dimension $2N$ and with the same (algebraic) eigenvalues, possibly degenerate.

Is there a simple criterion to tell whether there exists or not a symplectic orthogonal matrix $S$ that transforms $A$ into $B$  ?
$$B=S^\top A  S  $$

Can I build explicitly such a matrix ?

Thanks,
Olivier